# Import a JavaScript file into an HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express

I am having a big problem with linking JavaScript files into HTML files.

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Express App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>GET Requests</h1><br/>
        <input type="number" name="id" id="id-input>
        <button type="submit" onclick="findPerson()">Submit</button>
        <script src="./index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code looks just fine, in fact, here is my JavaScript code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = 'http://localhost:3000';
app.connect(server);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
});

const findPerson = () => {
    var ID = window.document.getElementById('id- 
    input').value;
    console.log(ID);
};

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('App is listening on port 8080');
});
```

Now, for some reason, when I inspect the page and go to the console, it says this:

```
Refused to execute script from 
'http://localhost:8080/index.js' because 
its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and 
strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

And also this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with 
a status of 404 (Not Found) index.js:1
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to load `Node.js` files into the browser. Separate your backend from your frontend concerns.

Comment: The script, you are trying to run needs to be running on a webserver with Node.js. Then, you can communicate with this webserver via e.g. Ajax requests. This can be done with a library like `axios`. You are mixing concerns here.

Comment: Your `index.js` need to be run for server side. e.g `node index.js`. And if you are starting Node.js development, then  you can start with starter kits with reading their `readme.md`. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

I can see two errors with your code:

- The 404 error means that your not linking to the right path, please check where is your index.js relative to your index.html
- Even if it will load it, your code can not be executed because it's a server side code. 
  When you're including scripts in your browser it should be only client side code

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. I made a seperate file for jQuery JS, and I tried to import it in the HTML. It didn't work. It still gave me errors about failed GET requests for the file. Any idea?

Comment: The idea is in the answer I sent. Do you understand the answer? I think you you miss some basics knowledge in web app (client/server)